# What impact can my Russia tourist visa denial have on my travel history?

Tags: visa-refusals

1. I was denied without reason. All paperwork in order.
2. I’m a UK resident of 8y. Live and work. Citizen Pakistan
3. I plan to visit Paris in January. Schengen Visa issue?
4. I plan to try again for Russia next year. Private visa issue?
5. How do I know if I was really refused. Stamp doesn’t say.
6. Do Russia and Schengen states share data on this?
7. Should I really care about this ?
8. I’ve had visas for UK / US others in past.

[image]

Comment: Please do not downvote. Explain

Comment: Please post separate questions for each issue. It seems you want to know two things (1) Will this stamp effect schengen visas (2) will this stamp effect future russian visas? Is so please ask two separate questions so some can answer the specific issues respectively. The question, in its current state, is [too broad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Makes sense but it’s too late. I can’t extract stuff from here to a new question because there’s answers and comments from Hanky Panky

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer then accept it as valid. Otherwise, edit this question to include just one issue and add a new question for the other one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Private visa issue?" We certainly can't tell you what to care about.

Comment: I already got my answer. Someone understood me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was denied without reason. All paperwork in order.

There is no such thing as *denied without reason*, the reason might not have been conveyed to you but there was obviously some reason for the denial.

> I plan to visit Paris in January. Schengen Visa issue?

Guess work but it won't be a big deal.

> I plan to try again for Russia next year. Private visa issue?

Guess work but depending upon your [other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124551/russia-tourist-visa-denied-embassy-refuses-to-give-reason) I guess you were going DIY for a country that prefers properly organized tours. You should be good if you enlist a Russian tour operator/travel agent for help.

> How do I know if I was really refused. Stamp doesn’t say.

You paid the fee for a visa and after the application process your passport was returned to you and the process was completed but did not result in a visa and there was no withdrawal of the application , it was definitely a denial.

> Do Russia and Schengen states share data on this?

Not through any publicly known treaty.

> Should I really care about this ?

Yes, care enough to mention it on all such applications in future that ask if you have ever had a denial.

**TL;DR**

Denial of a Russian visa is not really a big deal for future Schengen Applications for an applicant that is already a permanent resident of the UK and has s clean travel history. Don't bother too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought there is a central database of some sort that records visa denial.

Comment: @AliGajani do you mean central Russian database, or central global database?

Comment: Nope there is no such thing. Some countries do share this information but that doesn't mean every country does it with a central database. However please never be tempted to say **No** for a previous visa denial if ever asked by any country. Denial is bad but not as bad as deception - that attracts a ban.

Comment: Yes of course. I always speak the truth.

Comment: For my russia visa I am told to get private visa as I wanted to see my girlfriend. You are probably right about DIY bit. I was interviewed too. Told them traveling and to see my friend. Didn’t specify gender. They asked. Are they russian citizen. I said yes. Showed return tickets and hotel booking. End of interview.

Comment: @AliGajani if everything that you say on your other question (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124551/russia-tourist-visa-denied-embassy-refuses-to-give-reason) is true and you can afford another visa application I would say go ahead and reapply for your Russian visa using a Russian tour operator. I  think you were almost there.

Comment: Everything I say there is true absolutely and I think the problem can be me having a bloody Pakistani passport. Some guy called Coke suggests getting a notarized letter.

Comment: Coke is a legend. Let’s put it that way. He helps me in this forum quite a lot. I trust his judgement. So yes. Private visa OR Tourist visa with real tours. Notarized letter can be in there too for the latter. I’ll try again next year. I think private visa is very complicated for host.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am yet to get an ILR so I’m not quite permanent yet. I just have been in UK since 2009, studying, living and working. Now I have a BRP. Working since 2015. I believe what you said still holds true regarding you last point

Comment: Russia doesn't care about your visas from other countries. Since you got rejected by Russia, they will reject your next one. I would save my money and forget it. Having UK visas or residency doesn't mean squat to them.

Comment: @AussieJoe That's a funny answer. Having a visa rejected once doesn't mean you'll get your next one rejected. I don't think there's any truth to that. There are people who get US visas reject 2 times and get it on the third one.

Comment: @AliGajani this is not a US visa and you are not a US citizen, so your point is irrelevant. This is Russia, not USA, not Schengen or whatever else. You don't even know why you got denied! How is that even possible? I would find out ASAP. Something isn't right because the only way you get denied is if you didnt complete the paperwork right, or couldn't prove your citizenship. I think you are already blacklisted.

Comment: I don’t know what you’re talking about because all I’m talking about is that there is no logic behind what you initially said. They treat a new application differently. When I do get it one day, I’ll report back. Private visa was suggested to me and I was using a tourist one to see my friend. Probably the reason for rejection.

Comment: @AliGajani I have had 3 valid Russian tourist visas to visit my girlfriend (now fiancee) and I still think you are blacklisted. I am curious to see how it goes for ya. Good luck.

Comment: I was going for the same purpose. But it’s  all in the paperwork and your nationality really. But blacklisted. Haha, I hope not. Let’s see what happens. My research wasn’t that solid and I’ll be getting a UK passport soon so prospects might change.

Comment: @AliGajani did you declare your purpose as tourism or "staying with friends"? I read that a lot of people are denied because they do not go through proper tourism sponsorship. I know I pay a tourist agency to "sponsor" me, but after that, you change your hotel and address, once you have your tourist visa issued. You simply use the agency to get the visa.

Comment: Turns out I was doing a plain and simple DIY , tourist voucher from Hotels Pro, Hotel reservation , fully paid return tickets. All documents that were asked. Purpose was tourism. But I was interviewed at embassy and j told them I am going for travel and to see a friend. They asked are they a Russian citizen. I said yes. No gender was asked for. Passport came back few weeks later with no visa. I basically did what they asked for on the website but looks like I missed something.